# SQL use wildcard <% and placeholders <?> in a SELECT statement. (In python with sqlite3)

Tags: python, parameters, sqlite, wildcard

I am trying to go through a list of gene names and query them in my SQL database like this:

```
list_of_genes = ["IFNL", "TMPT", "G6PD", "UGT1A1", ...]
for gene in list_of_genes:
    sql.execute('''SELECT DISTINCT gene_symbol, haplo_function FROM Haplotypes 
                   WHERE gene_symbol LIKE "%" + ? + "%"
                   ''', (gene,))
```

What I want to accomplish with this is to get all records from my Haplotypes table where the `gene_symbol` is similar to my `gene` from `list_of_genes`.
A gene from the list could be called `IFNL` and a gene_symbol in the database could be like `IFNL*1` or something similar.
This query gives 0 results, so how can I add wildcards to a SELECT statement together with a placeholder?

If I query it like the following; I do get a lot of results, but not all, since some gene_symbols have added information besides the gene_name.

```
for gene in list_of_genes:
    sql.execute('''SELECT DISTINCT gene_symbol, haplo_function FROM Haplotypes 
                   WHERE gene_symbol LIKE  ?
                   ''', (gene,))
```

I am sorry if I'm asking simple or stupid questions, but I have tried to search for it, but could not find anything combining both <%> wildcards and ? placeholders/parameters.

Answer (score 0):

If I got your question right, you can try something like this:

```
cur.execute('SELECT * FROM t WHERE t.param LIKE ?', ("%" + val + "?",))
```

Comment: Indeed changing the place of the wildcards to outside of the statement works. instead of (gene,) I now use ("%" + gene + "%",) and it works! Thanks! (So a slight adjustment from your answer, replacing your second ? with a %)